# Is JAVA_HOME environment variable really required to run ElasticSearch?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

As per title,
is it really required to have JAVA_HOME set on the host PC? Can I run ElasticSearch by just specyfing the full path of the java.exe vm?

Comment: you need at minimum JRE to run elasticSearch. java.exe and jre are the same.

Comment: ok thanks, so there is no need for JAVA_HOME to be set, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly, if you look at the starting script of elasticsearch:

```
if [ -x "$JAVA_HOME/bin/java" ]; then
    JAVA="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
else
    JAVA=`which java`
fi
```

So basically, either you have $JAVA_HOME set, or you have installed Java in your system and the system knows its location (the `which java` should at least return a path when ran in a shell, something like */usr/bin/java*)

Comment: Ok thanks, but I guess I can modify the script and point it to a known location of java. I know it sounds weird and it's not recommended but I can just modify the script and not use the JAVA_HOME

Comment: Yes you can, the only thing you have to be careful of is when upgrading to new version